# How to turn off or turn on a several of filters when I write in a search text input in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<div class="item item-icon-right">
<input class="search" type="text" placeholder="search..." ng-model="searchText">
<button class="icon ion-search button-clear button-dark"></button>
            </div>
<ion-item ng-repeat="service in services | filter:{service_category_id:category_selected.id} | filter:{name:searchText} | filter:criteriaMatch(criteria)"
                      class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" type="item-text-wrap" href="#" ng-class='determineSelect(service.level)'>
                {{service.name}}
                <button class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right button-clear button-dark" ng-click="selectParent(service)"></button>
                <ion-option-button ng-show = "services_selected.indexOf(service.id)==-1" class="button-energized" ng-click="addInterest(service)">
                    Add
                </ion-option-button>
            </ion-item>
```

As you can see, in ng-repeat section I have 3 filters, but what I want is  when I start typing in the input(which also is a filter) all the filters in the ng-repeat section turn off, ans just the filter about the searchText(which is in ng-repeat also) turn on.
Thank you very much!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement your own filter and pass a variable to enable o disable it.

```
function conditionalFilter() {
  return function(data, searchIsEmpty) {
       if(searchIsEmpty){
           //filter your data, you can inject $filter angular built-in
           return filteredData
       }
       return data

  }
}
```

Then in your HTML, pass `searchText` as variable to the filters, if search text is not empty, your filters will be off.

```
<ion-item ion-item ng-repeat="service in services | conditionalFilter:{service_category_id:category_selected.id}:searchText | conditionalFilter:{name:searchText}:searchText | filter:criteriaMatch(criteria)"
class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" type="item-text-wrap" href="#" ng-class='determineSelect(service.level)'>
```